# Convergence of series of dependent random variable, central limit theorem

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

My friend and I have a problem on central limit theorem.

Given $X_1,X_2......$ are i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu$=0,  variance $\sigma^2=1$(may or may not be normally distributed). If we define: $Y_n=X_1X_2+X_2X_3+....X_{n-1}X_n$, how to show the  $\frac{Y_n}{n}\to N(0,1)$ when $n\to\infty$. i.e.
$$\frac{X_1X_2+X_2X_3+....X_{n-1}X_n}{\sqrt{n}}\to N(0,1),as \ n\to \infty$$

I am not sure denominator is n or n-1. It is obvious that $X_1X_2$ and $X_2X_3 $ are dependent, so I cannot use the standard central limit theorem. I also find the $\textit{Lindeberg-Feller CLT}$, but it is on the independent but not identically distributed random variables.

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: What type of convergence are you looking for? Convergence in probability, distribution, almost sure?

Comment: If you divide by $n$, there is LLN not CLT. The fraction converges to some constant, not to standard normal distribution.

Comment: I guess I need the convergence in distribution, but if wen can prove others, they also imply converge in distribution

Comment: As NcH points out, you are looking for convergence to 0 with prob 1 using the law of large numbers (LLN). You get that as a direct application of LLN by considering the terms in two groups (the odd terms and the evens).

Comment: Sorry I make a mistake, it should be sqrt(n) instead of n

Comment: I believe there is another small error, we have $\frac{\sum Y_n-\operatorname{E}[\sum Y_n]}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\sum Y_n]}}\to N(0,1)$ and we know that $\operatorname{E}[\sum Y_n]=\sum\operatorname{E}[Y_n]=n\mu=0$ and if the $Y_i$ were independent we would have $\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\sum Y_n]}=\sqrt{\sum \operatorname{Var}[Y_n]}=\sqrt{n\sigma}=\sqrt{n}$ and we would recover your expression but the variables aren't independent actually it should be

Comment: $\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[\sum Y_n]}=\sqrt{\sum (\operatorname{Var}[Y_n]+2\operatorname{Cov}[Y_i,Y_j]})=\sqrt{\sum \operatorname{Var}[Y_n]+2\sum \operatorname{Cov}[Y_i,Y_{i+1}]+2\sum_{i,j>i+1} \operatorname{Cov}[Y_i,Y_j]})=\sqrt{n\sigma^2+(n-1)\sigma^2+0}=\sqrt{2n-1}\sigma=\sqrt{2n-1}$